# Does the nginx "upstream" directive have a port setting?

Tags: nginx

I use `upstream` and `proxy` for load balancing.

The directive `proxy_pass http://upstream_name` uses the default port, which is 80.

However, if the upstream server does not listen on this port, then the request fails.

### How do I specify an alternate port?

my configuration:

```
http{
#...
upstream myups{
 server 192.168.1.100:6666;
server 192.168.1.101:9999;
}
#....
server{
listen 81;
#.....
location ~ /myapp {
 proxy_pass http://myups:81/;
}
}
```

nginx -t:

```
[warn]: upstream "myups" may not have port 81 in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:78.
```

Comment: Please edit this so it makes sense. I see what appears to be a fragment of an Nginx configuration and a vague (and internally nonsensical) description of an attempted solution. I don't see any indication of what the actual problem is, or that the questioner has read the available documentation.

Comment: As a `nginx` user I understood the question just by the title. Agreed, it belongs to SF.

Answer (score 59):

in your upstream configuration you have ports defined ( 6666 and 9999 ), those are the ports your backend servers need to listen on

the proxy_pass directive doesn't need an additional port configuration in this case.
Your nginx listens on `port 81` which you've defined in the `listen` directive

*Is this what you tried to do?*

```
http {
    #...
    upstream upstream_1{
        server 192.168.1.100:6666;
        server 192.168.1.101:9999;
    }

    upstream upstream_2{
        server 192.168.1.100:6661;  // other backstream port if you use port 81
        server 192.168.1.101:9991;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        #.....
        location ~ /myapp {
            proxy_pass http://upstream_1;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 81;
        #.....
        location ~ /myapp {
            proxy_pass http://upstream_2;
        }
    }
}
```